# Plotting 3D Data with ggplot2 without interpolation

Tags: r, ggplot2, 3d, contour

I am trying to plot 3D as contour curves or tiles with discrete data. I manage to do it with the using interpolation from `akima` package. However, I would also like to be able to generate a plot with the crude data. Initially I thought it would be as simples as just skipping the interpolation stage, but I think there may be some problems with irregular spaced data.

Here is the attempt with the `geom_raster` and you can see the type of data I have (I need to tranform the axis data):

## geom_raster - does not work

```
library(ggplot2)
library(akima)

x <- seq(from = 0.01,to = 1, by = 0.01)
y <- seq(from = 0.01,to = 1, by = 0.01)

xAxis <- x/(1+x*y)
yAxis <- x/(1+x*y)

df <- expand.grid(x,y)
xAxis <- df$Var1/(1+df$Var1*df$Var2)
yAxis <- df$Var2/(1+df$Var1*df$Var2)
z <- -1*((0.5-xAxis)^2 + (0.5-yAxis)^2)

df$x <- xAxis
df$y <- yAxis
df$z <- z

ggplot(df, aes(x, y, fill=z)) + 
   geom_raster() + 
   viridis::scale_fill_viridis()
```

The error message:

```
Error in matrix(NA_character_, nrow = nrow, ncol = ncol) : 
  invalid 'nrow' value (too large or NA)
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In f(...) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In f(...) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

I also tried `geom_tile()`, it does not produce any error message, but gives me an empty plot:

## geom_tile producing empty plot

```
library(ggplot2)
library(akima)

x <- seq(from = 0.01,to = 1, by = 0.01)
y <- seq(from = 0.01,to = 1, by = 0.01)

xAxis <- x/(1+x*y)
yAxis <- x/(1+x*y)

df <- expand.grid(x,y)
xAxis <- df$Var1/(1+df$Var1*df$Var2)
yAxis <- df$Var2/(1+df$Var1*df$Var2)
z <- -1*((0.5-xAxis)^2 + (0.5-yAxis)^2)

df$x <- xAxis
df$y <- yAxis
df$z <- z

ggplot(df, aes(x, y, fill=z)) + 
   geom_tile() + 
   viridis::scale_fill_viridis()
```

Finally, here is the working example with the interpolation from `akima` ´package.

## With Interpolation - works

```
library(ggplot2)
library(akima)

x <- seq(from = 0.01,to = 1, by = 0.01)
y <- seq(from = 0.01,to = 1, by = 0.01)

xAxis <- x/(1+x*y)
yAxis <- x/(1+x*y)

df <- expand.grid(x,y)
xAxis <- df$Var1/(1+df$Var1*df$Var2)
yAxis <- df$Var2/(1+df$Var1*df$Var2)
z <- -1*((0.5-xAxis)^2 + (0.5-yAxis)^2)

df$x <- xAxis
df$y <- yAxis
df$z <- z

im <- with(df, akima::interp(x, y, z, nx = 100, ny = 100))
df2 <- data.frame(expand.grid(x = im$x, y = im$y), z = c(im$z))

ggplot(df2, aes(x, y, fill=z)) + 
   geom_raster() + 
   viridis::scale_fill_viridis()
```

The main problem with `akima` is that for my original data it seems to throw some points away, which strangely does not occur with the faked data here.

Thanks!